# phpmailer/exim4 to outlook.com mail arrive to junk directory

Tags: email, exchange, spam, outlook, exim

I would like to send a simple, email address change confirmation email with php and exim4.
I tested my mail with lot of free email provider and everywhere arrived my email well except outlook.com.
In the outlook.com, my mail, arrived into the junk directory, but I don't understand why.
I have good dns, ptr, spf, dkim records and everything is "pass".

In the message I have 5 simple sentences and one link like this:

```
https://www.example.com/email-activation/1270a967d
```

This is some interesting line from my header:

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass, dkim=pass
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.21
CMM-X-SID-PRA: noreply@example.com
CMM-X-AUTH-Result: PASS
CMM-X-SID-Result: PASS
CMM-X-Message-Status: n:n
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 5
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;SFV:SPM;SFS:(28900001);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:5;SRVR:HE1EUR02HT176;H:SNT004-MC7F9.hotmail.com;FPR:;SPF:None;CAT:SPM;LANG:en;
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(444111334)(444112120)(82015046);SRVR:HE1EUR02HT176;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:HE1EUR02HT176;
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:22
SpamDiagnosticMetadata: Default
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: HE1EURHT176
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: HE1EUR02FT050.eop-EUR02.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SenderIP:1.2.3.4;WIMS-SPF:example%2ecom;WIMS-DKIM:example%2ecom;WIMS-822:noreply%40example%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:noreply%40example%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400140)(102420017);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;MIME-Version: 1.0
```

I think the problem is the SCL value "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 5", but I don't understand what is the problem with the simple mail with one link. 
Can somebody say to me, how can I resolve this and how can I find the reason?

BTW I tested my email with https://www.mail-tester.com/ and my score is 10/10.

Answer (score 1):

Try Marking it "Not SPAM" in your Hotmail/Microsoft Account once.
Then check if it lands on another MS account properly.

MS is notorious regarding New Naive IPs that are yet to build some reputation.

Sign UP to SNDS and also you need to send them a mail giving them your IPs for Whitelisting... which they usually do in a couple of working days
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&ccsid=635714983457075069